# How to create a setup of an Windows application using PowerBuilder

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder.net

I am a newbie for PowerBuilder and for Windows application. I have few projects which consists corresponding code in it and after merging all that I get the final product. The problem I am facing right now is that I don't know how to make a setup of my Windows app using PowerBuilder. If I can get step by step procedure with tiny explanation, I will be able to achieve it already. Have tried Google but ended up with complex confusion. I have created the .exe, but that .exe does not work on any other computer. So please guys help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to creating a setup program for your application: defining the files and other resources that need to deployed, and building those resources into a setup executable package.

For defining files and resources, you've made it impossible for anyone to even take a shot by referring to two very different (but similar origins) versions of the product in your tags: PowerBuilder (aka PowerBuilder Classic) and PowerBuilder.NET. The deployment requirements for apps built from each of these is very different. However, even if we knew, the best advice is to go through the [manuals](http://sybooks.sybase.com) and review what is required of the features of your specific application. (e.g. if you don't use rich text, deploying the files required to support it would be a waste). A generic list is, IMHO, just bad advice.

As far as building a setup package goes, the first decision is which package building software to pick (none comes with PowerBuilder). Any Windows setup package builder should do. I've used [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com/) and [Inno](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), vastly preferring the latter (after many years of using the former). I know you want steps to walk you through, but a walk through is impossible before picking the software, and frankly, walk throughs of these setup building software has been done elsewhere much better than I'd do.

The bottom line is that the answer isn't as simple as you seem to have been hoping, but it is attainable.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: What Terry said is great, wanted to add one thing. PB comes with a runtime packager program that builds a package of the components you need. This will help make sure you have all the run times needed.